# Load and manipulate on my page elements from different domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to load in a div from my page the content of a different domain page.
I've tried to use `<object>` or `<iframe>`, the content is loaded but I am not allowed to manipulate it with jQuery.
Also, I had the same error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'URL'. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'http://localhost:15297' is therefore not allowed access

, when I tried

```
$.get("URL", function (data) {
    $("#divID").append(data);
}
```

Is there any work around to load and manipulate content from different domain page with jQuery?

Comment: You can't do either in the browser if you don't control the code on remote page also. Alternative is use a server side proxy

Answer (score 0):

You need to organise connection between child and parent page using postMessage.

Seems like this lib could help you https://github.com/travist/seamless.js